# How to remove padding in the ZStack SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, padding, zstack

I'm getting weird padding when trying to put another VStack in ZStack. How to remove it?

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        VStack{
            Text("1")
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
        .background(Color.init(.green))

        ZStack{
            VStack{
                Text("2")
            }
            .frame(width: 210, height: 50)
            .background(Color.init(.blue))
            VStack{
                Text("3")
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
            .background(Color.init(.green))
        }

        VStack{
            Text("4")
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
        .background(Color.init(.green))
    }    
}
```

}

if I comment VStack with Text("2"), padding will disappear.

[image: Screenshot of weird padding]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) { // << here !!
```

Comment: I believe the question was for "ZStack" Not "VStack"

Comment: @avatarZuko, the question of topic starter was *how to remove weird padding* - and the reason was not in `ZStack`... how it is formulated does not matter in this case - this is a fix for provided code.

Answer (score -2):

You have provide different width in

```
VStack{
      Text("2")
}
.frame(width: 210, height: 50)
.background(Color.init(.blue))
```

the width is **210** and other element width is **200** 
provide the same width the padding will remove.

Comment: No, it will not remove. I am talking about vertical paddings between 1 and 3 / 3 and 4

Comment: okay.. 
This is because of the Top VStack view.
provide the spacing in this VStack to avoid this space/margin/padding.